# Separating response and header in PHP

Tags: php

The content returned to me from URL is:

```
53 GMT    
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent    
Connection: close    
HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc    
Paypal-Debug-Id: 6966608696d9    
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D2239325528%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc; Expires=Thu, 29 Dec 2016 21:30:53 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly    
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT    
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400    
Transfer-Encoding: chunked    
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  


8

VERIFIED

0
```

I only want to get verified response from it and remove other content. I searched and people recommended using list, but in my case when I used list, the response was empty while header had all the content. Any suggestions?
And what are these 2 numbers 8 and 0 referring to?

Comment: How did you get this response? Doesn't look like a standard HTTP response: usually header lines would not have blank lines between them. Two newlines is usually the separator between the headers and the body of the response...

Comment: @MacPrawn  Pasted it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking closer, I see the headers are separated from the body by *4* newlines... For some odd reason, your newlines are doubled everywhere...

To get the response body, you could use a regular expression:

```
if(preg_match('/^[\w\W]+?[\n]{4}([\w\W]+)$/', $response, $matches)) $response_body = $matches[1];
```

As to what those numbers are exactly, I could not tell you. That would hopefully be explained by whoever you are requesting the URL from... In that body, there's no standard, anyone can return anything in any way they like...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually stackoverflow added those irrelevant spaces in header.